# How to get the "index" of a draggable element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

For a sortable element, I would use `ui.item.index()`. Is there an equivalent for draggable elements?

```
$('.elem').draggable({
  start: function(event, ui){
    //How do I get the "index" of ui.item?
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [jquery.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) like you would anywhere else:

```
$('.elem').draggable({
    start: function () {
        var myIndex = $(this).index();
        $(this).text('I am #' + myIndex);    
    }
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4w5yz/3/).